# Give suggestions with user input position using autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I know **autocomplete** can help us to give word suggestions, however this js can only give a suggestion in the beginning of the input box.

Does anyone know how to use **autocomplete** or **other package** that can reach the same goal: Give suggestions as the user input characters or words. 
The suggestion should show below the INPUT character or word.

Answer (score 0):

With just a bit of research you can find enough plugins that can do that... A couple of those can be:

[Typeahead from twitter](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

[Jquery UI has an autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

And I've found a [List of autocomplete libraries.](http://techslides.com/list-of-autocomplete-plugins-and-libraries)

Comment: Yes, all the plugins can get the suggestions, but they are not what I want.Given a js: demo like this: [http://54.92.14.49/tip/auto.html]. Plugins such as autocomplete can give suggestions in a fixed position, the js I provided in the link can give suggestions in the position where my mouse is, my question is how can I change the the suggestion to the drop down list in my provided js?